# TypeScript - Define types of a class and its constructor arguments with minimal redundancy

Tags: typescript

I currently have a class like this:

```js
class Person {
    id?: string = uuid();
    name: string;

    constructor(data: Person) {
        _.merge(this, data);
    }
}
```

with 'uuid' being a function that generates an id and '_' being lodash.

My problem is that I have a function that needs the id:
`function savePersonInDb(p: Person & { id: string }) {...}` and so TypeScript does not accept to call it on a `new Person()` because id is optional, even though it is always instantiated when calling the constructor.

I know I could do something like:

```
interface PersonData {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
}

class Person {
    id: string = uuid();
    name: string;

    constructor(data: PersonData) {
        _.merge(this, data);
    }
}
```

but I don't really like the idea of having to write all the attributes twice. Do you see any way I could do what I want in an easier way?

Oh and I forgot to mention it but in my actual project I have way more than 2 attributes so I would really appreciate not to have to write them twice for every classes.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to create a type from `Person` that takes all the type definitions except `'id'` which is made optional ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwJIBMA8AKgHxQC8UA3gLABQU9UCOA-AFxQDOwATgigOa0AvlABksALYJghADRQA5EwVFatAPTqoABQjcOqACJpgaRhyhoArsCQSTCAMaYMIKFbA4TEHFADuABYQKDp6BiEIFo4BaAI+tKCQofpGJmbkcIiomLh4uikoRADcajSanGgAbhD54VgohgBGUABWVlxQpgDWEBa1qLQAZlYojlkhHFU1Yaj1TQAUkAXs-SgAlJRCpY4YaBx9MyHUdAxM7Fy8AmSKCkVQ5VZWTPNrJSf06BIQ5zx8-NcKW60BhQL4SRp6ACM7BQVnBemuAAY3iDymCIdwAEyWFC+AxQAY0YEMRyoC5WMZIbjzLymFaHYymDbHEGorQAfQAdF9uPwIPNgAFIvJaWhXsT6FsaFKNFomOYCfBkOgMLRSSgOktwtcUBA-MlwvMWQxPt9FMBesAFLIJaCIPDuNCoABWYTiollLS6-Va1AExotCBjKDOEIQ9wcHyc2iTaqrOaNRaHNZAA)):

```
type OptionalId<T> = {
    id?: string
} & Omit<T, 'id'>

// PersonData is automatically updated when Person is changed
type PersonData = OptionalId<Person>;

// savePersonInDb just takes Person
function savePersonInDb(person: Person) {}

class Person {
    id: string = ''; // uuid();
    name: string = '';
    member1: number = 0;
    // member2 and so on

    constructor(data: PersonData) {
        // _.merge(this, data);
    }
}

// id is optional
const person = new Person({
    name: 'test',
    member1: 5
});

// new person object can be used.
savePersonInDb(person)
```

Comment: `{[K in Exclude<keyof T, 'id'>]: T[K]}` can be written more simply as `Omit<T, 'id'>`.

Comment: That is correct, forgot about that one. I will update the answer.

Comment: That's perfect! I don't know why I didn't think of something like that... Thanks a lot!